# If i have a list of pairs ex. (String, int) how to add every int in strings are the same to one single pair

Tags: eclipse, ocaml

i have this problem where i have a list of pairs string int and i want to sum the total of ints with the same String ex:
list -> [("a",1);("b",1);("a",1);("c",1)] should return
list -> [("a",2);("b",1);("c",1)] order doesnt mather will sort later´

for now i have this

```
let rec merge l = 
  match l with
  | [] -> []
  | (c1,n1)::(c2,n2)::xs -> 
    if c1 = c2 then
      (c1, n1+n2)::merge xs
    else
      something i cant think of yet
```

thats my train on thougth but i know it wont work yet

ps i cant use imperative stuff suported by ocaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you assume that your list is sorted, the "something i cant think of yet" is simply copying the head of the list and applying the function recursively to the tail: `(c1,n1)::merge ((c2,n2)::xs)`.

Comment: oh i realised now, if i sort first there will be no repeated elements, my problem was if A appeared 2 times it off order it would appear 2 times, a sorted list by string wont

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this seems like a perfect place to apply a [`Map`](https://v2.ocaml.org/api/Map.html) which is *not* an imperative feature in OCaml.

We can fold over the input list. If the current "key" can be found in the map, we add it back to the map with the values combined. If it's not found, we add the key with its current value into the map. The `bindings` function can be used to extract a list of tuples.

```
module StringMap = Map.Make (String)

let merge lst =
  lst 
  |> List.fold_left
       (fun map (k, v) -> 
          match StringMap.find_opt k map with
          | None -> StringMap.add k v map
          | Some v' -> StringMap.add k (v + v') map)
       StringMap.empty
  |> StringMap.bindings
```

With result:

```
# merge [("a", 1); ("b", 1); ("a", 1); ("c", 1)];;
- : (string * int) list = [("a", 2); ("b", 1); ("c", 1)]
```